# TypeError when importing requests from python

Tags: python, python-requests, typeerror

I'm having problems using the requests library. I used pip to install it and I also intalled through github and the installation goes just fine. But when I try to import the lib, I get this error:

```
Python 2.7.14+ (default, Mar 13 2018, 15:23:44) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 12, in <module>
    from cryptography import x509
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.base import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/extensions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.general_name import GeneralName, IPAddress, OtherName
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/general_name.py", line 18, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.name import Name
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/name.py", line 28, in <module>
    _ASN1_TYPE_TO_ENUM = dict((i.value, i) for i in _ASN1Type)
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
>>>
```

I saw in another post a person saying something about the PATH, but I didn't understand... Something related to a conflict between /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin. I don't know if this have something to do with it.
I also have used pip2.7 to install the lib and it shows in the `pip list` command. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/4020 and tried the `sudo pip uninstall enum` followed by `sudo pip install enum34`?

Comment: Oh man, I saw this before, but for some reason I forgot to uninstall the enum. Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer for future readers that find this page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the cryptography module. It can also be found on the [github page](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/4020). The solution seems to be that you need to replace the enum package:

```
pip uninstall enum
pip install enum34
```

Note that you need to use `sudo pip` if you are using packages from `/usr/`